# Document tagging in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

If I have millions (or even billions) of objects in this scheme:

```
{ id: ...,
name: ...,
desc: ... }
```

And I want to add tags to each of those objects, what would be the most efficient way to do this?

Later, I want to be able to count objects for each tag, see all objects that have tag X, etc.

Comment: You'll need to loop through each document, ideally from the MongoDB console, and add a tag field. Probably as an array. There's no special way to make it fast. You'll likely want to enable an index after you complete using `ensureIndex`.

Answer (score 0):

For this you must use update, the command will add only the new fields:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/

In addition to counts recommend that the calculation is on the side of your application and structure of the collection have a field where that parameter is stored and updated as appropriate.

```
{ id: ...,
name: ...,
desc: ...,
count: 9 }
```